# Transform characters to portuguese special characters

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this string:

```
>>> str(row['letra'][0])
'<p>[Baviera]<br/>Menina, me d\xc3\xa1 sua m\xc3\xa3o, pense bem antes de agir<br/>Se n\xc3\xa3o for agora, te espero l\xc3\xa1 fora, ent\xc3\xa3o deixe-me ir<br/>Um dia te encontro nessas suas voltas<br/>Minha mente \xc3\xa9 m\xc3\xb3 confus\xc3\xa3o<br/>Solta a minha m\xc3\xa3o, que eu sei que c\xc3\xaa volta<br/>O tempo mostra nossa dire\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o</p>'
```

And i want to transform it to portuguese special characters, but when I try:

```
>>> unicode(str(row['letra'][0]).decode('utf-8')).encode('utf-8')
'<p>[Baviera]<br/>Menina, me d\xc3\xa1 sua m\xc3\xa3o, pense bem antes de agir<br/>Se n\xc3\xa3o for agora, te espero l\xc3\xa1 fora, ent\xc3\xa3o deixe-me ir<br/>Um dia te encontro nessas suas voltas<br/>Minha mente \xc3\xa9 m\xc3\xb3 confus\xc3\xa3o<br/>Solta a minha m\xc3\xa3o, que eu sei que c\xc3\xaa volta<br/>O tempo mostra nossa dire\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o</p>'
```

The characters doesn't came as I want. 
How can I transform 'd\xc3\xa1' to 'dá', for example?

Comment: `print(str(row['letra'][0]))` will render those characters as you want them.

Comment: this works only for print, but when I sent it to a mysql database, it still hasn't the correct characters. @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ could you help me?

Comment: That's how non-unicode char are stored. As long as you open a connection to mysql setting charset to `UTF-8`, when you read and print the content, it will be displayed as your wish. But you won't see a *string* such as `"mão"`, you'll see `"m\xc3\xa3o"` instead.